# async.waterfall() breaks on passing callback to bcrypt.hash()

Tags: node.js, callback, async-await, bcrypt

I am new to async/await and have set up a basic node.js server that handles form data for user registration. Below is my code

```
async.waterfall([async function(callback){ //Method 1

            const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10/*, () => {  //breakpoint
                    console.log("Hash Generated Successfully");
            }*/);
            return hash;

        }, function(hash, callback){ //Method 2
            console.log(`The value of passed arg is: ${hash}`);
            callback(null, 'success');

        }], function(err, result){
            if(err){
                throw err
            }
            else {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
```

In `Method 1`, if i don't provide the callback to `bcrypt.hash()`, the code works correctly and the value of hash is printed. However, if i do provide the callback, i get this output: 
`The value of passed arg is: undefined`. 
So, i have two questions here.
1) Why does `async.waterfall()` break on providing callback to `bcrypt.hash()`?
2) What is the other way to do error handling, other than callbacks?

Comment: Have you tried passing the requisite parameters to the callback function? (err, hash) for example. Also, I'm not sure if async await is required here being that you're already in an sync operation (async.waterfall).

Comment: @silencedogood (err, hash) worked! Thanks. i was using async/await because i was calling the callback(null, hash) function outside the callback of bcrypt.hash(). So instead of returning hash value, Method 1 was returning a promise object. Please post your answer so that i may accept it.

Comment: Sure! Glad this solved your issue. Answer posted. I see your logic for using async/await. I may have went about this differently but I suppose it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing the requisite parameters to the bcrypt callback function is a necessity if you plan on including the anonymous function as a parameter. For ex:

```
const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10, (err, hash) => {  // Added err, hash params.
                console.log("Hash Generated Successfully");
        });
return hash;
```